# What is "the languages object definition"?

Tags: meaning

Example with a context ([The Object-Oriented Thought Process (3rd Edition)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672330164)):

> As stated often in this introduction,my vision for the first edition was primarily a conceptual book.Although I still adhere to this goal for the second and third editions, I have included several application topics that fit well with object-oriented concepts. For the third edition I expand on many of the topics of the second edition and well as include totally new chapters.These revised and updated concepts
>
> - XML is used for object communication.
> - Object persistence and serialization.
> - XML integrated into **the languages object definition**.
> - Adding properties to attributes.
> - XML-based Internet applications.
> - Client/Server technologies.
> - Expanded code examples in Java, C# .NET and VB .NET.

Does anybody here have at least a passing familiarity with the term to be able to actually explain what it means? Because I can't make sense of it and was unable to find anything online.

Comment: Looks to me like there's a typo: it should be *language's*, thus "the definition of object employed by the language".

Comment: I agree on the typo.  It's not at all clear, however, what that sentence-fragment means, and I've read quite a few books on C#, Smalltalk, OOP, etc.  It could refer to the ability to instantiate an object from XML. But that's just a guess.

Comment: @TRomano That's how I'm reading it as well. I would think the best way to decide would be to have the 2nd and 3rd edition of the book in front of you and compare them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That passage is very poorly written; for example, note the "and well as" (a blend of "and" and "as well as"), and the dangling "These revised and updated concepts" introducing the list.

As StoneyB says above, it should definitely be "the language's object definition" rather than "the languages object definition"; and I'll add that the "language" must surely be the relevant object-oriented language (such as Java or C#) rather than referring to XML itself; but beyond that, we can only speculate. The book has sections that discuss using XML as an object serialization format for persistence and for transfer between applications; perhaps it's referring to one of these? (But then, why list "XML is used for object communication", "Object persistence and serialization", and "XML-based Internet applications" separately?)

Given the apparently lack of proofreading in this passage, my best guess is that it was originally written as a rough draft of ideas of what should be improved/expanded in the third edition, and that it never got updated after the third edition was actually completed. Perhaps the author had originally intended to include a section on code-generation frameworks that can create class definitions based on XML schemata.